# What is the best way to apply default date formatting to all such fields in an ASP.NET MVC 3 app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, date

My goals are:

- Display *all* dates in `d MMM yyyy` format

  - Default/existing values on first page load
  - Anything entered by the user, then round-tripped via the server
- Add `class="behaviour-date-picker"` to the input field so that I can show a jQuery date picker
- Build on top of the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` infrastructure
- Still show bad data values such as `12 Joone 2010` after a server roundtrip, with the appropriate validation error message

Here's an example model:

```
public class DebugDatesStub
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
}
```

The `DisplayFormat` attribute doesn't solve my scenario because it doesn't apply to round-tripped values. (User fills in form, submits it, gets the same form back because of some server-side validation issue - date is still shown in the original format they entered instead of being reformatted.)

Comment: By 'is there a better way', do you mean from a coding perspective? It would be great to put some of that logic into some kind of helper or extension method, so that it's decoupled from the view and unit-testable.

Comment: More that I'd like to kill all that code completely...

From a testing perspective, I have a stub page with just a date field which is then covered by functional tests so I can test full roundtrips, the date picker JS, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render the field on the page with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)
```

Create this code in `~\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Date.cshtml`:

```
@using System.Globalization
@model DateTimeOffset?

@{
    var propertyState = ViewData.ModelState[ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName];
    var displayValue =
        propertyState != null && propertyState.Errors.Any() ? propertyState.Value.AttemptedValue :
        ViewData.Model.HasValue ? string.Format("{0:d MMM yyyy}", ViewData.Model.Value) :
        string.Empty;

    ViewData.ModelState.SetModelValue(
        ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName,
        new ValueProviderResult(displayValue, displayValue, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, new { @class = "behaviour-date-picker" })
```

Comment: An alternative idea - what about overloading TextBoxFor just for DateTime properties? I.e.: public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, DateTime>> expression, object htmlAttributes) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it something like this (code taken as sample from WebGrid, hopefully it will give you an idea):

```
@{
    var viewDictionary = new ViewDataDictionary<DebugDatesStub>(new DebugDatesStub());
}

...
ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(d => d.DateTimeOffset, viewDictionary).PropertyName,
ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(d => d.DateTimeOffset, viewDictionary).DisplayName,
format: (item) => { return new HtmlString(item.DateTimeOffset.ToString("MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss")); })
...
```